# VBA - How to optimize VBA code to run faster?

Tags: vba, loops, optimization

I'm running the code below and it takes around 8 hours to complete. It chooses 20 projects (out of 38) by maximizing the utility of the projects while keeping the budget constraint. There is also a constraint on the min/max number of projects of ClassA, ClassB and ClassA and ClassB combined.

The code works fine, however it takes a long time to complete. Do you know how to optimize this code to make it run faster (if possible)?

'''

```
    Sub CalculateOptions()
    
    Dim InputProjects(1 To 38, 4) As Single
    Dim TopChoices(1 To 5, 1 To 22) As Single
    Dim CurrentChoice(1 To 22) As Single

    
    TotalHorInArray = 22
    TotalVertInArray = 5
    
    MinimalProjectsClassA = 9
    MaximalProjectsClassA = 14
    MinimalProjectsClassB = 5
    MaximalProjectsClassB = 9
    MinimalProjectsClassAandClassB = 15
    MaximalProjectsClassAandClassB = 19
    
    Budget = 49
    NumberOfProjects = 38
    
    'Read input
    For x = 1 To NumberOfProjects
        For y = 1 To 4
        InputProjects(x, y) = Cells(2 + x, 4 + y)
        Next
    Next
    
    For a = 1 To NumberOfProjects
     For b = a + 1 To NumberOfProjects
      For c = b + 1 To NumberOfProjects
       For d = c + 1 To NumberOfProjects
        For e = d + 1 To NumberOfProjects
         For f = e + 1 To NumberOfProjects
          For g = f + 1 To NumberOfProjects
           For h = g + 1 To NumberOfProjects
            For i = h + 1 To NumberOfProjects
             For j = i + 1 To NumberOfProjects
              For k = j + 1 To NumberOfProjects
               For l = k + 1 To NumberOfProjects
                For m = l + 1 To NumberOfProjects
                 For n = m + 1 To NumberOfProjects
                  For o = n + 1 To NumberOfProjects
                   For p = o + 1 To NumberOfProjects
                    For q = p + 1 To NumberOfProjects
                     For r = q + 1 To NumberOfProjects
                      For s = r + 1 To NumberOfProjects
                       For t = s + 1 To NumberOfProjects
                       
                        ' Utility
                        UtilityChoice = InputProjects(a, 1) + _
                                InputProjects(b, 1) + _
                                InputProjects(c, 1) + _
                                InputProjects(d, 1) + _
                                InputProjects(e, 1) + _
                                InputProjects(f, 1) + _
                                InputProjects(g, 1) + _
                                InputProjects(h, 1) + _
                                InputProjects(i, 1) + _
                                InputProjects(j, 1) + _
                                InputProjects(k, 1) + _
                                InputProjects(l, 1) + _
                                InputProjects(m, 1) + _
                                InputProjects(n, 1) + _
                                InputProjects(o, 1) + _
                                InputProjects(p, 1) + _
                                InputProjects(q, 1) + _
                                InputProjects(r, 1) + _
                                InputProjects(s, 1) + _
                                InputProjects(t, 1)
    
                        ' Check if utility constraint is met (only want to show the top 5 combinations in the output)
                        If UtilityChoice > max5 Then
    
                            ' Budget
                             budgetChoice = InputProjects(a, 3) _
                                        + InputProjects(b, 3) _
                                        + InputProjects(c, 3) _
                                        + InputProjects(d, 3) _
                                        + InputProjects(e, 3) _
                                        + InputProjects(f, 3) _
                                        + InputProjects(g, 3) _
                                        + InputProjects(h, 3) _
                                        + InputProjects(i, 3) _
                                        + InputProjects(j, 3) _
                                        + InputProjects(k, 3) _
                                        + InputProjects(l, 3) _
                                        + InputProjects(m, 3) _
                                        + InputProjects(n, 3) _
                                        + InputProjects(o, 3) _
                                        + InputProjects(p, 3) _
                                        + InputProjects(q, 3) _
                                        + InputProjects(r, 3) _
                                        + InputProjects(s, 3) _
                                        + InputProjects(t, 3)
                         
                            ' Check if budget constraint is met
                            If budgetChoice <= Budget Then
                         
                                ' Check number of projects per Class
                                ClassOfProject = InputProjects(a, 4) + _
                                                InputProjects(b, 4) + _
                                                InputProjects(c, 4) + _
                                                InputProjects(d, 4) + _
                                                InputProjects(e, 4) + _
                                                InputProjects(f, 4) + _
                                                InputProjects(g, 4) + _
                                                InputProjects(h, 4) + _
                                                InputProjects(i, 4) + _
                                                InputProjects(j, 4) + _
                                                InputProjects(k, 4) + _
                                                InputProjects(l, 4) + _
                                                InputProjects(m, 4) + _
                                                InputProjects(n, 4) + _
                                                InputProjects(o, 4) + _
                                                InputProjects(p, 4) + _
                                                InputProjects(q, 4) + _
                                                InputProjects(r, 4) + _
                                                InputProjects(s, 4) + _
                                                InputProjects(t, 4) + 10
                               
                                ProjectsClassA = Right(ClassOfProject, 2) - 10
                                ProjectsClassB = Round(ClassOfProject / 100, 0)
                                ProjectsClassAorB = ProjectsClassA + ProjectsClassB
                                
                                ' Check if minumum and maximum constraint is satisfied for total projects of class A and B
                                If ProjectsClassA >= MinimalProjectsClassA And ProjectsClassA <= MaximalProjectsClassA _
                                    And ProjectsClassB >= MinimalProjectsClassB And ProjectsClassB <= MaximalProjectsClassB And _
                                        ProjectsClassAorB >= MinimalProjectsClassAandClassB And ProjectsClassAorB <= MaximalProjectsClassAandClassB Then
                                    
                                    ' Project specifics
                                    CurrentChoice(1) = InputProjects(a, 2)
                                    CurrentChoice(2) = InputProjects(b, 2)
                                    CurrentChoice(3) = InputProjects(c, 2)
                                    CurrentChoice(4) = InputProjects(d, 2)
                                    CurrentChoice(5) = InputProjects(e, 2)
                                    CurrentChoice(6) = InputProjects(f, 2)
                                    CurrentChoice(7) = InputProjects(g, 2)
                                    CurrentChoice(8) = InputProjects(h, 2)
                                    CurrentChoice(9) = InputProjects(i, 2)
                                    CurrentChoice(10) = InputProjects(j, 2)
                                    CurrentChoice(11) = InputProjects(k, 2)
                                    CurrentChoice(12) = InputProjects(l, 2)
                                    CurrentChoice(13) = InputProjects(m, 2)
                                    CurrentChoice(14) = InputProjects(n, 2)
                                    CurrentChoice(15) = InputProjects(o, 2)
                                    CurrentChoice(16) = InputProjects(p, 2)
                                    CurrentChoice(17) = InputProjects(q, 2)
                                    CurrentChoice(18) = InputProjects(r, 2)
                                    CurrentChoice(19) = InputProjects(s, 2)
                                    CurrentChoice(20) = InputProjects(t, 2)
                                    CurrentChoice(21) = UtilityChoice
                                    CurrentChoice(22) = budgetChoice
    
                                    ' Read in project specifics if utility is in the top 5 (and constraints above are met)
                                   If UtilityChoice > max1 Then
                                       max5 = max4
                                       max4 = max3
                                       max3 = max2
                                       max2 = max1
                                       max1 = UtilityChoice
                                       For Z = 1 To TotalHorInArray
                                           TopChoices(5, Z) = TopChoices(4, Z)
                                           TopChoices(4, Z) = TopChoices(3, Z)
                                           TopChoices(3, Z) = TopChoices(2, Z)
                                           TopChoices(2, Z) = TopChoices(1, Z)
                                           TopChoices(1, Z) = CurrentChoice(Z)
                                       Next
                                   ElseIf UtilityChoice > max2 Then
                                       max5 = max4
                                       max4 = max3
                                       max3 = max2
                                       max2 = UtilityChoice
                                       For Z = 1 To TotalHorInArray
                                           TopChoices(5, Z) = TopChoices(4, Z)
                                           TopChoices(4, Z) = TopChoices(3, Z)
                                           TopChoices(3, Z) = TopChoices(2, Z)
                                           TopChoices(2, Z) = CurrentChoice(Z)
                                       Next
                                   ElseIf UtilityChoice > max3 Then
                                       max5 = max4
                                       max4 = max3
                                       max3 = UtilityChoice
                                       For Z = 1 To TotalHorInArray
                                           TopChoices(5, Z) = TopChoices(4, Z)
                                           TopChoices(4, Z) = TopChoices(3, Z)
                                           TopChoices(3, Z) = CurrentChoice(Z)
                                       Next
                                   ElseIf UtilityChoice > max4 Then
                                       max5 = max4
                                       max4 = UtilityChoice
                                       For Z = 1 To TotalHorInArray
                                           TopChoices(5, Z) = TopChoices(4, Z)
                                           TopChoices(4, Z) = CurrentChoice(Z)
                                       Next
                                   ElseIf UtilityChoice > max5 Then
                                       max5 = UtilityChoice
                                       For Z = 1 To TotalHorInArray
                                           TopChoices(5, Z) = CurrentChoice(Z)
                                       Next
                                   End If
                               
                               End If
                            End If
                        End If
                        
                       Next
                      Next
                     Next
                    Next
                   Next
                  Next
                 Next
                Next
               Next
              Next
             Next
            Next
           Next
          Next
         Next
        Next
       Next
      Next
     Next
    Next
    
    ' Write output to excel
    For x = 1 To TotalVertInArray
        For y = 1 To TotalHorInArray
            Range("OutputCalculation").Offset(x, y) = TopChoices(x, y)
        Next
    Next
    
    Range("A1").Select
    
    End Sub
```

'''

Thanks,

Walther

Comment: In "Write output to excel" you can just put the array into a range.  Do you know where it is being held up?  Does up until "Write output to excel" take the time for example 1st off?

Comment: With that depth of looping it is surprising that your code only takes hours to run. The best way to improve performance is to throw this code away and use a radically different approach, one that uses the solver to solve a well-formulated discrete optimization problem. The problem doesn't seem like a huge one (from an operations research perspective). A better approach might just take seconds to run.

Comment: Since in the innermost iteration only `t` is changing, you can place all other accesses outside that loop. Continue with the next innermost loop. A bit of thinking should yield more efficient code.

Comment: I didn't mean to sound so harsh in my last comment, but the core problem is that your fundamental algorithm is a brute-force search through C(38,20) = 33.6 billion possibilities. Doubtless you could make that brute-force search a more efficient brute-force search, but 33.6 billion is still 33.6 billion and VBA is not a speed demon. On the other hand, this is a 0-1 integer programming problem of the sort that the solver can handle using sophisticated algorithms implemented in something like C. If you want a speedup that is really significant, you really do need a very different approach.

Comment: Thanks alot for your replies. @JohnColeman: I agree with you and it's not harsh in my view. I agree with you. However, I don't know how to set it up as a different optimization problem. If there are any ideas for that, happy to hear them! I'm not familiar with C unfortunately, only VBA.. @ Nathan: thanks for your comment. It's being held up by the for loops. All bits help though, will change the write output to excel part.